# MFP8.0 Adapter deploy failed

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-cli

We updated our Developer Kit and QA environment to product version 8.0.0.00-20170220-1900. We try to build the adapters and deploy the adapter to remote server using MFP CLI. But the deploy to server is failed with MAVEN plugin error.

Logs:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model 

for metlife:NotificationsAdapter:adapter:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for com.ibm.mfp:adapter-maven-plugin is missing. @ line 44, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building NotificationsAdapter 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- adapter-maven-plugin:8.0.2017021701:deploy (default-cli) @ NotificationsAdapter ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.824 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-28T12:36:16-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.ibm.mfp:adapter-maven-plugin:8.0.2017021701:deploy (default-cli) on project NotificationsAdapter: Execution default-cli of goal com.ibm.mfp:adapter-maven-plugin:8.0.2017021701:deploy failed: A required class was missing while executing com.ibm.mfp:adapter-maven-plugin:8.0.2017021701:deploy: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>com.ibm.mfp:adapter-maven-plugin:8.0.2017021701
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/var/root/.m2/repository/com/ibm/mfp/adapter-maven-plugin/8.0.2017021701/adapter-maven-plugin-8.0.2017021701.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/var/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient-osgi/4.3.4/httpclient-osgi-4.3.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/var/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.4/httpclient-4.3.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/var/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3.2/httpcore-4.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/var/root/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/var/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.3.4/httpmime-4.3.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/var/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient-cache/4.3.4/httpclient-cache-4.3.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/var/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/fluent-hc/4.3.4/fluent-hc-4.3.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/var/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore-osgi/4.3.2/httpcore-osgi-4.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/var/root/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore-nio/4.3.2/httpcore-nio-4.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/var/root/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/var/root/.m2/repository/javax/xml/jaxp-api/1.4.2/jaxp-api-1.4.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/var/root/.m2/repository/org/mozilla/rhino/1.7R4/rhino-1.7R4.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/var/root/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[project>metlife:NotificationsAdapter:1.0-SNAPSHOT, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException

Error deploying adapter: NotificationsAdapter
```

Comment: Is the issue specific to this one adapter or common?

Comment: Looks like it built successfully. Are you able to successfully deploy the adapter manually through the console, and it works as expected? It definitely *looks* like it can't find `LogFactory`, but the jar that should contain it is listed...

Answer (score 0):

If you can build successfully then Try to deploy manually from Operational Console.

Answer (score 0):

From MFP Console try to deploy the adapter: your issue get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change or add version detail (in-case missing) pom.xml as following. It resolved issue for me.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mfp</groupId>
            <artifactId>adapter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <version>8.0.2020110500</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

In my case it deploy using adapter-maven-plugin:8.0.2022030307:deploy and facing same error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.ibm.mfp:adapter-maven-plugin:8.0.2022030307:deploy (default-cli) on project Project: Execution default-cli of goal com.ibm.mfp:adapter-maven-plugin:8.0.2022030307:deploy failed: A required class was missing while executing com.ibm.mfp:adapter-maven-plugin:8.0.2022030307:deploy: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
```